# Unhandled Exception: WebSocketException: Bad response 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header

Tags: flutter, websocket

I am facing Unhandled Exception: WebSocketException: Bad response 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header this error when i am running this code on button click.

///CODE

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      'ws://35.154.43.70:8090/chatdemo/pho-socket.php');

  channel?.stream.listen((message) {
    // channel?.sink.add('received!');
  });
}
```

URL:   ws://35.154.43.70:8090/chatdemo/php-socket.php